# Vertx HttpProxy is "losing" Http Request parameters

Tags: java, reverse-proxy, vert.x

I am using a Vertx HttpProxy as a reverse proxy whose "origin" is an address that I am POSTing form data to. For some reason, my form data is not reaching the origin.

My code is fairly straightforward. I am sending requests through this proxy from the following HTML:

```
    <form action="/meeting" method="POST">
        <input style="font-size: 20px;" id="mainparam" name="mainparam" />
        <button type="submit" style="font-family: 'Arbutus Slab', serif;">
            <b style="font-family: 'Arbutus Slab', serif; font-size: 20px;">Join&nbsp; Meeting</b>
        </button>
    </form>
```

My Proxy setup code, as it works in the start() function in a verticle, is below:

```
@Override
public void start() throws Exception
{
   HttpServerOptions options = new HttpServerOptions();
   HttpClientOptions clientopt = new HttpClientOptions();
  
   options.setMaxHeaderSize(6000);
   options.setMaxInitialLineLength(100000);
   options.setTcpKeepAlive(true);
  
   clientopt.setMaxHeaderSize(6000);
   clientopt.setMaxInitialLineLength(100000);
   clientopt.setTcpKeepAlive(true);
  
   HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient(clientopt);
  
   HttpProxy proxy = HttpProxy.createProxy(client);
  
   proxy.origin(8080,"localhost");
  
   HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer(options);
  
   server.requestHandler(proxy);
  
   server.listen(8010,result->{
      if(result.succeeded())
         System.out.println(3,"Proxy Server has started!");
      else if(result.failed())
         System.out.println("Proxy Server start FAILED. Reason: "+result.cause());
  });
}
```

The page submits the contents of an input box that is called "mainparam" My origin server (localhost on a different port from the listening server) should be able to get the contents of a parameer called "mainparam".

My origin server uses a servlet to process requests. In my doPost() method, I receive an HttpServletRequest object that gets the parameter using:

```
String mainparam = req.getParameter("mainparam");
```

When I do directly to the server on my browser, when I call getParameter() my mainparam string is whatever I entered into the input box on the webpage.

When I access the server from my browser through my proxy, getParameter() returns null.

Is there some setup or configuration that I need to do in order to stop my proxy from dropping my parameters? What is causing my proxy to lose my parameters when I post through it?

ADDED INFO:

I have been running debugging sessions on the HttpProxy implementation class in order to determine what is happening to parameters once a request comes through a proxy. I have been examining the contents of the HttpServerRequest object that is passed into the HttpProxyImpl's handleProxyRequest() method.

What I am finding is that there is a property called "params" in the HttpServerRequest object that I am assuming is supposed to contain request parameters. I believe that params is a MultiMap. Regardless of the type and number of parameters I put into my POSTing html file, the params property is always null.

I am continuing my examination of the code, but it looks to me as if parameters simply are not being transferred from the HTTP request into the HttpProxy's list of parameters. This means that there is a serious bug in Vert.x's HttpProxy implementation.

Someone please correct me if I am wrong, but so far it looks like I have found a bug that limits the usability of the current HttpProxy implementation.

Comment: Has anyone bothered to answer your question here? I can give some more useful info: this problem has nothing to do with the HttpProxy implementation. It appears to be fundamental to the Vertx routers. I am having a similar problem using a regular router doing a POST.I am discovering that apparently parameters get lost when doing any GET or POST on "vanilla" Vertx Web. I will be posting about this problem soon. Hopefully someone will address it...